# Не могу получить JSON данные, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, nginx, symfony3, php-fpm

Пытаюсь вернуть `JSON` ответ, но при попытке получения, выдает

> "500 Internal Server Error".

Сайт лежит на vps хостиге. На локальном сервере `php bin/console server:run` все работает прекрасно.
Сайт на `Symfony3` c использование `FOSUBundle`.

***В логе пишет***

> "GET /admin/posts HTTP/1.1" 500 507

[Конфиг `nginx`](https://pastebin.com/mcFemED0):

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    gzip        on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  144645.simplecloud.club;
        root /var/www/site/web;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос связан не с получением JSON ответа, а с получением 200 ответа от сервера вообще (а что именно он выдает, это уже десятое дело). Скорее всего неправильно настроен web-сервер, к тому же у вас идет проксирование с nginx на php-fpm, в неправильной настройке которого и может быть ошибка (проверьте эту связку).

Comment: Все остальные данные получаю нормально.
То что проксирутся знаю, но не знаю что с эти делать.

Comment: попробуйте по этому же адрес получить какой-нибудь обычный ответ (не JSON). по сути JSON это просто формат выдачи данных, который не влияет на ответ сервера.

Comment: я что-то сделал и все заработало) Проблема было в симфони.
Но совет "попробуйте по этому же адрес получить какой-нибудь обычный ответ (не JSON)."  - помог, спасибо.